# Concise code to get four identical diagrams equally spaced in four quadrants

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have a forest drawn, an arrow directed rightward, an arrow directed southward, and a title. I would like to have the diagram repeated three more times so that they fill the quadrants of a square - the surrounding square is not drawn, though. Is there a way to do this with the "\foreach" command? Also, is there a way to draw the dots indicating vertices with the "\foreach" command? My code is really bulky for such a simple diagram.

How do I get the two arrows drawn properly? I want one arrow drawn from the middle of eastern side of the bounding box of the current diagram to the the middle of the western side of the bounding box of another copy of the diagram. Similar for the other arrow.

Lastly, I would like the title below the diagram of the four forests. Right now, there is some interference with one of the arrows.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm]

%A forest is drawn. One of the vertices is labeled P.
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);

%An arrow directed eastward is drawn.
\draw[-latex] (2.5,2) to[out=30,in=150] (6.5,2);
\path node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ({(2.5+6.5)/2},2){Move to the\\right};

%An arrow directed southward is drawn.
\draw[-latex] (1,-5) to[out=240,in=120] (1,-9);
\path node[anchor=east, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ({2-0.15},{(-5-9)/2}){Move to\\the bottom};


%A description for the diagram is written.
\path node[draw, text width=0.5\linewidth, inner sep=2mm, align=center] at (current bounding box.south)
{Four diagrams of a forest;\\
some have vertex $P$, and\\
some have omitted vertex $P$,\\
and some have omitted vertex $P$\\
and edges with an endpoint at $P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you provide a sketch of desired result? BTW, you use vey old `pgfplots`. It is time to upgrade to recent version (1.18) (which fix many bugs and define new features)

Comment: @Zarko  I much improved the diagram that I want.  You can see it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643754/drawing-arrows-between-the-entries-in-a-matrix-environment-within-tikz .  Please do not post a response unless the only edits you make are edits that appropriately position the arrows between the entries of the matrix.  I want to keep the `matrix environment`.

Comment: Please, elaborate your question. A link is even more disturbing,  Where are arrows? Where you you require a matrix? What is your problem? Why I should not response or even edit my answer?

Comment: @Zarko  Incredibly, I had forgotten to include the code for the arrows in this other post. The code for them is there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add bounding box for each entry in order to see effect. You could comment those lines to make the entry without bounding box. Here are two versions of the code:

> Diagrams in first row aligned at their southern edges

This version looks better in my opinion. Because the angled arrows form a relative good circle.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,bending}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1},
pics/fpic/.style={code={#1}}, x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm]
%A forest with a vertex P is drawn.

\matrix[row sep=15em, column sep=15em]{\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (firstb) at (current bounding box.south) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (firstr) at (current bounding box.east) {};
}};
&\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(0,2) coordinate (R)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=east] at ($(P) +(-0.15,0)$){$P$};
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(R) +(0,0.15)$){$R$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (R) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (R);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [shift={(0,-1)},inner sep=7.5pt] (secondl) at (current bounding box.west) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (secondb) at (current bounding box.south) {};
}}; \\
\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (v4);
\draw (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (thirdt) at (current bounding box.north) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (thirdr) at (current bounding box.east) {};
}};
&\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (fourthl) at (current bounding box.west) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (fourtht) at (current bounding box.north) {};
}}; \\
%\path coordinate (midpoint_of_southern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.south);
%\path coordinate (midpoint_of_eastern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.east);
};
\draw[-latex] (firstb) to[out=240,in=120] node[text width=2cm,align=center,right]{Move to the bottom}  (thirdt);
\draw[-latex] (firstr) to[out=30,in=150] node[text width=2cm,align=center,below=2mm]{Move to the right} (secondl);
\draw[-latex] (secondb) to[out=-60,in=60] node[text width=2cm,align=center,left]{Move to the bottom} (fourtht);
\draw[-latex] (thirdr) to[out=-30,in=-150] node[text width=2cm,align=center,above=2mm]{Move to the right} (fourthl);
\path node[draw, text width=0.4\linewidth, inner sep=2mm, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.south) +(0,-2)$)
{Four diagrams of a forest;\\
some have vertex $P$, and\\
some have omitted vertex $P$,\\
and some have omitted vertex $P$\\
and edges with an endpoint at $P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Diagrams in first row vertically centered.

In this version, the arrow in red rectangle looks a little weird to me.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,bending}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1},
pics/fpic/.style={code={#1}}, x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm]
%A forest with a vertex P is drawn.

\matrix[row sep=15em, column sep=15em]{\pic[shift={(0,1)}]{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (firstb) at (current bounding box.south) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (firstr) at (current bounding box.east) {};
}};
&\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(0,2) coordinate (R)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=east] at ($(P) +(-0.15,0)$){$P$};
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(R) +(0,0.15)$){$R$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (R) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (R);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (secondl) at (current bounding box.west) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (secondb) at (current bounding box.south) {};
}}; \\
\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (v4);
\draw (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (thirdt) at (current bounding box.north) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (thirdr) at (current bounding box.east) {};
}};
&\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% comment this to make entry without bounding box
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (fourthl) at (current bounding box.west) {};
\node [inner sep=7.5pt] (fourtht) at (current bounding box.north) {};
}}; \\
%\path coordinate (midpoint_of_southern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.south);
%\path coordinate (midpoint_of_eastern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.east);
};
\draw[-latex] (firstb) to[out=240,in=120] node[text width=2cm,align=center,right]{Move to the bottom}  (thirdt);
\draw[-latex] (firstr) to[out=30,in=150] node[text width=2cm,align=center,below=2mm]{Move to the right} (secondl);
\draw[-latex] (secondb) to[out=-60,in=60] node[text width=2cm,align=center,left]{Move to the bottom} (fourtht);
\draw[-latex] (thirdr) to[out=-30,in=-150] node[text width=2cm,align=center,above=2mm]{Move to the right} (fourthl);
\path node[draw, text width=0.4\linewidth, inner sep=2mm, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.south) +(0,-2)$)
{Four diagrams of a forest;\\
some have vertex $P$, and\\
some have omitted vertex $P$,\\
and some have omitted vertex $P$\\
and edges with an endpoint at $P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want. I like that you added a frame around each diagram.

Comment: Please make two edits for me. First, shorten the arrows a bit - maybe by 7.5pt or 12.5pt - so that the tails and heads of the arrows are not obscured by the frames of the boxes. Second, vertically center the frame in the northeast quadrant. Right now, the bottom edges of the frames in the northwest and northeast quadrants are aligned. This makes the tail and the head of the arrow between them at different heights.

Comment: @user74973 I did the edit. I didn't vertical align the frame (it will make other arrows looks bad). instead I shift the down the arrow point location. Is this looks better?

Comment: @Tom  Thanks! Yes, the arrows are nicely spaced from the frames of the diagrams, and the tail and head of the top horizontal arrow are level.

Comment: @Tom Please position the title with ($(current bounding box.south) +(0,-2)$).  I will accept your answer immediately.

Comment: @user143462 The second code you won't wanted right? I will delete it.

Comment: @Tom  The code for the current diagram is what I need.

Comment: @Tom  I *really* appreciate your patience with this!

Comment: @user143462 You are welcome!

Comment: @Tom  My mistake. I want the second code that you wrote - the code for the box that is vertically centered in the northeast quadrant to be featured. That is the one that I *need*. It would actually be good to have both diagrams, though. Maybe you could label them "Diagrams in first row aligned at their southern edges" and "Diagrams in first row vertically centered."  Both codes will be useful to the members learning to use `TikZ`.

Comment: @Tom  I see how you got the centering of the diagram in the northeastern quadrant. Since vertex R is 2 units above vertex P, in this diagram, you just moved the diagram in the northwestern quadrant up half the distance between P and R in the diagram in the northeastern quadrant with the option `[shift={(0,1)}]` in the `\pic` command.

Comment: @user143462 Yes. You can shift up the northwestern entry with `[shift={(0,1)}] before \pic command` or shift down the northeastern entry with `[shift={(0,-1)}] before \pic command`. The results are identical. I have added both version codes in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Your question is not entirely clear, especially where are arrows and box with some description.
- Since in comment you say, that is not desired that I would edit my first answer, I delete it and decide that if I will have a spare time,  I will eventually write a new answer.
- Now, after find some spare time, decided to try my luck again by guessing what your picture should look like. Ii this I consider a first version of question on link given in your comment.
- However, I'm still not sure, what is your problem. Unfortunately so far you aren't willing to show us a sketch of what you after.

**Edited:**
It seems that @Tom have crystal bal in which he sow what OP is after (unfortunately mine is broken). Considering his guessing, the code for solution can also be:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending,
                calc,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm,
                    auto,
                    node distance = 45mm and 19mm,
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
     nodes = {font=\footnotesize}, %   inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize
arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[flex]}, thick, shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1,
              align=center},  
 pics/fpic/.style = {code={#1}}, 
                    ]
%A forest with a vertex P is drawn.

\matrix  (M) [row sep=13em, column sep=9em
             ] 
{
% first "forest"
\pic{fpic={\draw
        (0,0)                   node[dot, label=$P$] (P) {}
     -- (240:2)                 node[dot] (v1) {}
     -- ($(v1)+(-0.75,0)$)      node[dot] (v2) {}
        ($(v1)+(260:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v3) {}
        (0,-2.5)                node[dot] (v4) {}
     -- ($(v4) +(250:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v5) {}
     -- ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$)     node[dot] (v6) {}
        ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v7) {}
     -- ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v8) {}
        (2,0)                   node[dot] (v9) {}
     -- ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v10)  {}
        ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$)    node[dot] (v11)  {};
\draw
    (P) -- (v4)
    (P) -- (v9)
    (v1) -- (v3)
    (v4) -- (v7)
    (v9) -- (v11);
    }};
    &   % second "forest"
\pic{fpic={\draw
        (0,2)                   node[dot, label=$R$] (R) {}
     -- (0,0)                   node[dot, label=left:$P$] (P) {}
     -- (240:2)                 node[dot] (v1) {}
     -- ($(v1)+(-0.75,0)$)      node[dot] (v2) {}
        ($(v1)+(260:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v3) {}
        (0,-2.5)                node[dot] (v4) {}
     -- ($(v4) +(250:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v5) {}
     -- ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$)     node[dot] (v6) {}
        ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v7) {}
     -- ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v8) {}
        (2,0)                   node[dot] (v9) {}
     -- ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v10)  {}
        ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$)    node[dot] (v11)  {};
\draw
    (P) -- (v4)
    (P) -- (v9)
    (v1) -- (v3)
    (v4) -- (v7)
    (v9) -- (v11);
    }};                 \\
% third "forest"
\pic{fpic={\draw
        (0,0)                   node[dot, label=$P$] (P) {}
        (240:2)                 node[dot] (v1) {}
        ($(v1)+(-0.75,0)$)      node[dot] (v2) {}
        ($(v1)+(260:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v3) {}
        (0,-2.5)                node[dot] (v4) {}
     -- ($(v4) +(250:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v5) {}
     -- ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$)     node[dot] (v6) {}
        ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v7) {}
     -- ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v8) {}
        (2,0)                   node[dot] (v9) {}
     -- ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v10)  {}
        ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$)    node[dot] (v11)  {};
\draw[dashed]   (P) -- (v1) 
                (P) -- (v4)
                (P) -- (v9);
\draw   (v2) -- (v1) -- (v3)
        (v4) -- (v7)
        (v9) -- (v11);
}};
    &   % fourth "forest"
\pic{fpic={\draw
        (0,0)                   node[dot, label=$P$] (P) {}
     -- (240:2)                 node[dot] (v1) {}
     -- ($(v1)+(-0.75,0)$)      node[dot] (v2) {}
        ($(v1)+(260:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v3) {}
        (0,-2.5)                node[dot] (v4) {}
     -- ($(v4) +(250:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v5) {}
     -- ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$)     node[dot] (v6) {}
        ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v7) {}
     -- ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$)    node[dot] (v8) {}
        (2,0)                   node[dot] (v9) {}
     -- ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$)     node[dot] (v10)  {}
        ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$)    node[dot] (v11)  {};
\draw
    (P) -- (v4)
    (P) -- (v9)
    (v1) -- (v3)
    (v4) -- (v7)
    (v9) -- (v11);
    }};                 \\
};
% arrows on circle
\draw[arr=1em]   (M.center) ++ (110:45mm) arc (110: 65:45mm) 
            node[pos=0.5,above] {move to\\ the right};
\draw[arr=1em]
    (M.center) ++ (245:45mm) arc (245:295:45mm) 
            node[pos=0.5,below]  {move to\\ the bottom};
\draw[arr=1em]
    (M.center) ++ (175:45mm) arc (175:205:45mm) 
            node[pos=0.5,left] {move to\\ the right};
\draw[arr=1em]
    (M.center) ++ (  5:45mm) arc (  5:-25:45mm)
            node[pos=0.5,right]  {move to\\ the bottom};
    
% arrow directed southward
\node[draw, text width=0.5\linewidth, align=left,
      below = 3mm of M]
     {\textbf{Four diagrams of a forest:}\\
      some have vertex $P$, some have omitted vertex $P$,
      and some have omitted vertex $P$ and edges with an endpoint at $P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

From comparison of MWE in question as well with in a @To answer, you can observe, that code in above MWE is much shorter and simpler.

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: This is close.  Three edits would need to be made.  First, the title is not in the right place. You can position it properly with `($(current bounding box.south) +(0,-2)$)`. Second, I would like the diagram in the northeast quadrant to be vertically centered. Right now, the southern edges of the boxes containing the diagrams in the northwest and northeast quadrants are aligned. Third, the tail of the horizontal arrow should start at the center of the eastern side of the box containing the diagram in the northwest quadrant.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake that I made in my post yesterday.

Comment: I see your edits (and sarcasm). Now, read carefully - I wrote that "I would like the diagram in the northeast quadrant to be vertically centered" in the first row. Also, your arrow between the diagrams in the first row do not go between the midpoints of the eastern and western edges of the bounding boxes.

Comment: I do like how you drew the other arrows, though.

Comment: @user143462, no one prohibit to do this. In `tikz` package documentation are in chapter  *16 Arrows*, page 190 -- 220 thoroughly described. You can select desired on and with it replace ones used in my answer. BTW, one sketch gives more information than 1000 words.

Comment: I do not know what the options `shorten >=#1` and `shorten <=#1` do.  I typically like to have my options in each draw command. Perhaps I would want to shorten the horizontal arrows by a different amount than the vertical arrows. In you code, how much are they shortened?

Comment: @user143462 `arr=1em` , means `shorten >=1em` and `shorten <=1em`. So both side be shorted by 1em.