# Making coordinates at the southern and eastern points of a \pic box

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put coordinates at the midpoints of two sides of the bounding box of a diagram that is contained in a `\pic` box. I am planning to have four similar diagrams in four quadrants, and I want to draw arrows between the `\pic` boxes. I can cite these coordinates when locating the tails for the two arrows emanating from the current diagram, which would be positioned in the northwestern quadrant. Why do I get an error with the following commands?

```
\path coordinate (midpoint_of_southern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.south);
\path coordinate (midpoint_of_eastern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.east);
```

I put a `%` in front of these commands in the following code so that it will compile.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,bending}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}



\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1},
pics/fpic/.style={code={#1}}, x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm]
%A forest with a vertex P is drawn.

\matrix[row sep=4.5em, column sep=4.5em]{\pic{fpic={
\path (0,0) coordinate (P)
(240:2) coordinate (v1) ($(v1) +(-0.75,0)$) coordinate (v2) ($(v1) +(260:0.75)$) coordinate (v3)
(0,-2.5) coordinate (v4)
($(v4) +(250:1.75)$) coordinate (v5) ($(v5) +(210:1.5)$) coordinate (v6) ($(v4) +(350:1.75)$) coordinate (v7) ($(v7) +(260:1.75)$) coordinate (v8)
(2,0) coordinate (v9) ($(v9) +(45:0.75)$) coordinate (v10) ($(v9) +(285:0.75)$) coordinate (v11);
\path node[anchor=south] at ($(P) +(0,0.15)$){$P$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v8) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (v11) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\draw (v1) -- (v3);
\draw (P) -- (v4) -- (v5) -- (v6);
\draw (v4) -- (v7) -- (v8);
\draw (P) -- (v9) -- (v10);
\draw (v9) -- (v11);
}}; \\
%\path coordinate (midpoint_of_southern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.south);
%\path coordinate (midpoint_of_eastern_side_of_original_forest) at (current bounding box.east);
};
%
%



\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Comment: At first sight, it seems that the error is produced by the definition of your coordinates `midpoint...` inside the matrix environment.  But anyway, looking at your code in general, I have at least two questions: 1) Why do you need `matrix`? 2) Why do you introduce a `pic` for your graph?  A `pic` is useful if used many times (haing the same structure).  But as you define it, the code will be different each time.

Comment: @Daniel N  I was asking about this because I eventually wanted four identical diagrams (or similar diagrams) drawn in four quadrants. You can see that post here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643051/concise-code-to-get-four-identical-diagrams-equally-spaced-in-four-quadrants.

Comment: Well, I continue thinking that `matrix` is not necessary.  You want a graph with almost a fixed structure to be used four times.  OK for the `pic` object.  But not for the  `current bouunding box`; this is the box of the whole image at the moment when the command is invoked.  It will work for the first graph but not for the next ones! You need maybe to use the node `local bounding box`.  If it is not clear what I'm saying, I could post an answer...